# How does UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none work?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I understand it's supposed to "remove" the separators, but that's not truly the case:

1. If you look at the view's hierarchy, you would see `_UITableViewCellSeparatorView` being added as the cell's subview.
2. The separator's `isHidden` property is also `false`.
3. The separator's `alpha` is `1.0`.
4. The separator's frame is within the cell's bounds so it's not clipped.

How then are the separators "removed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the cell separator style is set to None, there is one `_UITableViewCellSeparatorView` being added, which has a `nil` background color.

[image: the first _UITableViewCellSeparatorView in the cell's view hierarchy]

[image: the background property of the first _UITableViewCellSeparatorView]

If the separator style is set to Single Line, you'll see that an additional separator view is present for every cell, which has a non-nil background color. That separator view is actually the one being presented as a line.

[image: the second _UITableViewCellSeparatorView in the cell's view hierarchy]

[image: the background property of the second _UITableViewCellSeparatorView]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Can I ask why is there an additional separator view(the nil one)?

Comment: @RayTso My guess is the same as shim's - those might help in the establishment of the cell structure of the table view.

Answer (score 1):

If I run "Debug View Hierarchy" with separators turned on, I see two `_UITableViewCellSeparatorView`s in each cell.

One has a `nil` background color, the other has the default colour.

If I run it with separators off, I only see one separator view, and its background colour is nil.

So it seems that when the separators are off the view being removed is the one with the background colour.

Not sure why there is an extra view in the hierarchy, maybe one for aesthetics and one for positioning cell content.